# Comparing two arrays, checking for matching values

Tags: arrays, jinja2, hubspot, hubl

Using HubL (as I'm building a module in HubSpot), I have two arrays:

1. `topics` : Which is a list of topics.
2. `all_tags`:  Which is an array of all the blog tags in the system.

If I dump out these arrays, this is what it will return:

- `{{ topics }}` prints the following: `[Data, Accounting, Insight]`
- `{{ all_tags }}` prints the following: `[Accounting, Press, Data]`

So essentially, `{{ topics }}` has a tag ("Insight") that doesn't exist in the system yet.

What I'm trying to do is to create a third array, which will contain matching results from the two above arrays. For example, `topics_final`, once returned, should print `[Data, Accounting]`.

But, when printing `{{ topics_final }}`, the array is empty.

**What I've tried:**

```
<!-- this gets all tags -->
{% set all_tags = blog_topics( blog_id , 250) %}

<!-- create arrays -->
{% set topics = [] %}
{% set topics_final = [] %}

<!-- append topic data to the array -->
{% for item in module.add_topics.topics %}
  {% set topic_option = item|striptags %}
  {% do topics.append( topic_option ) %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- check if topic tags exists in HubSpot -->
{% for topics in all_tags %}
  {% if topics in all_tags %}
    {{ topics }}
    <!-- results with above 
    Data, Accounting, Insight
    -->  
  {% else %}
    else
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

With the above, it just prints out the `{{ topics }}`, even though `Insight` isn't in the `all_tags` array.

**Note**: Tagging `Jinja2` as the syntax is similar

Comment: Why don't you do this inside the controller or a twig extension?

Comment: @DarkBee - How do you mean?

Comment: Meaning this should not be the responsibility of `twig`. It's more convenient to do this in your controller or a `twig` function/filter

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the filter [`reject`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#reject) and the built in test [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#in) could help you achieve this.

Sadly, it seems the `reject` filter does not accept negating a test, still, you can reject all the elements of `topics` that are not in `all_tags` then reject the said elements from the `topics` list.

So that ends with:

```
{{ topics | reject('in', topics | reject('in', all_tags) | list) | list }}
```

Switch yields:

```
[
    "Data",
    "Accounting"
]
```